# 'void com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap.clear()' on a null object reference

Tags: android, android-fragments, google-maps-android-api-2, android-mapview

In my App I am parsing the string like "hospital" from the MainActivity in onDrawerItemSelected() to google map which is defined in a fragment to show nearby hospitals..

But when i am calling this method of HomeFragment named showPlaces(int position) to show the nearby places named by the string the error occurs as:

'void com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap.clear()' on a null object reference

This is my whole Project:

Layout of MainActivity:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"android:clickable="true"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<!-- Framelayout to display Fragments -->
<LinearLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">
<LinearLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:id="@+id/container_toolbar">
<include
layout="@layout/toolbar"
android:id="@+id/toolbar"/>
</LinearLayout>

<FrameLayout
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:id="@+id/container_body"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    />
</LinearLayout>
<fragment
    android:layout_width="@dimen/nav_drawer_width"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/fragment_navigation_drawer"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    app:layout="@layout/fragment_navigation_drawer"
    tools:layout="@layout/fragment_navigation_drawer"
    android:name="mayur.projectwork3.FragmentDrawer"
    />



<!-- Listview to display slider menu -->
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>



MainActivity.java
package mayur.projectwork3;

import android.support.v4.view.GravityCompat;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements FragmentDrawer.FragmentDrawerListener {

private static String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();

private Toolbar mToolbar;
private FragmentDrawer drawerFragment;
HomeFragment homeFragment = new HomeFragment();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);

    setSupportActionBar(mToolbar);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);

    drawerFragment = (FragmentDrawer)getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_navigation_drawer);
    drawerFragment.setUp(R.id.fragment_navigation_drawer, (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout), mToolbar);
    drawerFragment.setDrawerListener(this);

    // display the first navigation drawer view on app launch
    displayView(0);
}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }



    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}



@Override
public void onDrawerItemSelected(View view, int position)
{
homeFragment.showPlaces(position);
}



private void displayView(int position) {
    Fragment fragment = null;
    String title = getString(R.string.app_name);
    switch (position) {
        case 0:
            fragment = new HomeFragment();
            break;
        default:
            fragment = new HomeFragment();
            break;
    }

    if (fragment != null) {
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();

        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.container_body, fragment);
        fragmentTransaction.commit();

        // set the toolbar title
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle(title);
    }
}
}

Layout of HomeFragment:


<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context="mayur.projectwork3.HomeFragment">

<com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" />
</LinearLayout>


HomeFragment.java:

package mayur.projectwork3;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.location.Location;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;



public class HomeFragment extends Fragment
{
String[] mPlaceType=null;
String[] mPlaceTypeName=null;
GPSTracker gpsTracker;
double mLatitude=0;
double mLongitude=0;

HashMap<String, String> mMarkerPlaceLink = new HashMap<String, String>();

GoogleMap googleMap;
MapView mapView;

public HomeFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}



@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_map, container, false);
    mapView = (MapView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.map);
    mapView.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setUpMap();

    // Inflate the layout for this fragment

    return rootView;
}



public void setUpMap()
{
    gpsTracker = new GPSTracker(this.getActivity());
    googleMap = mapView.getMap();
    googleMap.getUiSettings().setMyLocationButtonEnabled(false);
    googleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);

    try {
        MapsInitializer.initialize(this.getActivity());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    LatLng latLng = new LatLng(gpsTracker.getLatitude(),gpsTracker.getLongitude());

    googleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));
   googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(12));
}

@Override
public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
    super.onAttach(activity);
}

@Override
public void onDetach() {
    super.onDetach();
}

private String downloadUrl(String strUrl) throws IOException {
    String data = "";
    InputStream iStream = null;
    HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
    try{
        URL url = new URL(strUrl);

        // Creating an http connection to communicate with url
        urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

        // Connecting to url
        urlConnection.connect();

        // Reading data from url
        iStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();

        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(iStream));

        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();

        String line = "";
        while( ( line = br.readLine()) != null){
            sb.append(line);
        }

        data = sb.toString();

        br.close();

    }catch(Exception e){
        Log.d("Exception loading url", e.toString());
    }finally{
        iStream.close();
        urlConnection.disconnect();
    }
    return data;
}
/** A class, to download Google Places */
private class PlacesTask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String> {

    String data = null;

    // Invoked by execute() method of this object
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... url) {
        try{
            data = downloadUrl(url[0]);
        }catch(Exception e){
            Log.d("Background Task",e.toString());
        }
        return data;
    }

    // Executed after the complete execution of doInBackground() method
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result){
        ParserTask parserTask = new ParserTask();

        // Start parsing the Google places in JSON format
        // Invokes the "doInBackground()" method of the class ParseTask
        parserTask.execute(result);
    }
}

public void showPlaces(int position)
{
    gpsTracker = new GPSTracker(this.getActivity());


    if(isAdded())
        mPlaceType = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.places_type);

        String type = "hospital";
        mLatitude =gpsTracker.getLatitude();
        mLongitude =gpsTracker.getLongitude();

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?");
        sb.append("location="+mLatitude+","+mLongitude);
        sb.append("&radius=5000");
        sb.append("&types="+type);
        sb.append("&sensor=true");
        sb.append("&key=AIzaSyAED02xYclV3_jIri8Clz37DbZjeze-XSw");

        // Creating a new non-ui thread task to download Google place json data
        PlacesTask placesTask = new PlacesTask();

        // Invokes the "doInBackground()" method of the class PlaceTask
        placesTask.execute(sb.toString());

}

/** A class to parse the Google Places in JSON format */
private class ParserTask extends AsyncTask<String,Integer,List<HashMap<String,String>>>{

    JSONObject jObject;

    // Invoked by execute() method of this object
    @Override
    protected List<HashMap<String,String>> doInBackground(String... jsonData) {

        List<HashMap<String, String>> places = null;
        PlaceJSONParser placeJsonParser = new PlaceJSONParser();

        try{
            jObject = new JSONObject(jsonData[0]);

            /** Getting the parsed data as a List construct */
            places = placeJsonParser.parse(jObject);

        }catch(Exception e){
            Log.d("Exception",e.toString());
        }
        return places;
    }

    // Executed after the complete execution of doInBackground() method
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(List<HashMap<String,String>> list){

        // Clears all the existing markers
        googleMap.clear();

        for(int i=0;i<list.size();i++){

            // Creating a marker
            MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions();

            // Getting a place from the places list
            HashMap<String, String> hmPlace = list.get(i);

            // Getting latitude of the place
            double lat = Double.parseDouble(hmPlace.get("lat"));

            // Getting longitude of the place
            double lng = Double.parseDouble(hmPlace.get("lng"));

            // Getting name
            String name = hmPlace.get("place_name");

            // Getting vicinity
            String vicinity = hmPlace.get("vicinity");

            LatLng latLng = new LatLng(lat, lng);

            // Setting the position for the marker
            markerOptions.position(latLng);

            // Setting the title for the marker.
            //This will be displayed on taping the marker
            markerOptions.title(name + " : " + vicinity);

            // Placing a marker on the touched position
            Marker m = googleMap.addMarker(markerOptions);

            // Linking Marker id and place reference
            mMarkerPlaceLink.put(m.getId(), hmPlace.get("reference"));
        }
    }
}



@Override
public void onResume() {
    mapView.onResume();
    super.onResume();
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    mapView.onDestroy();
}

@Override
public void onLowMemory() {
    super.onLowMemory();
    mapView.onLowMemory();
}
```

}

Comment: The error "'void com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap.clear()' on a null object reference" means that you are calling the clear() method on a GoogleMap object that is actually null. Just study what happens in your setUpMap() method. Probably mapView.getMap() returns null. You can check out e.g. [this discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24446982/getmap-return-null-on-android-with-google-maps-api-v2) for some things to check when using a GoogleMap and narrow down your exact problem.

Comment: Sir please help me !!!

Comment: Well there are things like getting your own API key and adding it to the app's manifest file and such. Did you follow Google's tutorial at [https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/intro](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/intro)? It explains how to properly get started with the Maps API. You can also find plenty of [previous discussions](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=google+maps+getmap%28%29+null) about getMap() returning null.

Comment: but its not returning getMap() null, but map.clear() is returning null. And yeah i have added all those things like API key and all...

Comment: please dont rank down my query, so that other can answer it...

Comment: The problem is that `HomeFragment homeFragment = new HomeFragment();` is not the right way to work with fragments. You should not just instantiate a one like that. The fragment's `onCreateView()` is never called and it's the only place where `googleMap` is assigned a value. So `googleMap` is still null when you call `clear()`. Either add `HomeFragment` to the main activity's layout (like with the drawer fragment) or use the `FragmentManager` to display it programmatically. See the documentation and tutorials for the details.

Comment: Thanks Markus, however i had found this very mistake by my own.. But thankyou very very much.. and plz remove the -1 from my question so that my reputation can increase..

Comment: Someone else voted your question down. Probably because NullPointerException questions are so common, often trivial and people often post them without really showing any serious effort at solving -- like at least including a crash log.